# Removing <a href="#" tags python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, tags, beautifulsoup

```
arg = urllib2.urlopen(argv[1]).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(arg)
a_tags = soup.find_all('a') #so this stores a list with all the <a href="" /a> tags
```

and i need ONLY those that DO NOT LINK TO SAME PAGE (without the symbol # in href)

anyone pls....

Answer (score 2):

You can match the `href` attribute with a function:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=lambda value: value.startswith('#')):
    a.extract()
```